# kubernetes - use-case to choose deployment over daemon-set

Tags: kubernetes

Normally when we scale up the application we do not deploy more than 1 pod of the same service on the same node, using daemon-set we can make sure that we have our service on each nodes and would make it very easy to manage pod when scale-up and scale down node. If I use deployment instead, there will have trouble when scaling, there may have multiple pod on the same node, and new node may have no pod there.

I want to know the use-case where deployment will be more suitable than daemon-set.

Comment: whats the problem of one node not having a pod? Your ingress controller will take care of routing to whereever the pods may be.

Comment: I once have tried to scale nodes up and scale it down again with the same number of replicas. Once scaled down, pod on   old node got destroyed and got created on existing node, so one node will have more than 1 pod of the same service.

Comment: This can be solved using PodAntiaffinity, see my answer

Comment: Thank you, from all of the answer here I decided to change my service to use deployment because it have no need to run on every node, and I should set anti-affinity to the pod so that when node is down, pod of the same deployment will not get on the same node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cluster runs dozens of services, and therefore runs hundreds of nodes, but for scale and reliability you only need a couple of copies of each service.  Deployments make more sense here; if you ran everything as DaemonSets you'd have to be able to fit the entire stack into a single node, and you wouldn't be able to independently scale components.

I would almost always pick a Deployment over a DaemonSet, unless I was running some sort of management tool that *must* run on *every* node (a metric collector, log collector, *etc.*).  You can combine that with a HorizontalPodAutoscaler to make the size of the Deployment react to the load of the system, and in turn combine that with the cluster autoscaler (if you're in a cloud environment) to make the size of the cluster react to the resource requirements of the running pods.

Cluster scale-up and scale-down isn't particularly a problem.  If the cluster autoscaler removes a node, it will first move all of the existing pods off of it, so you'll keep the cluster-wide total replica count for your service.  Similarly, it's not usually a problem if every node isn't running every service, so long as there are enough replicas of each service running *somewhere* in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There are two levels (or say layers) of scaling when using deployments:

1. Let's say a website running on kubernetes has high traffic only on Fridays.
2. The deployment is scaled up to launch more pods as the traffic increases and scaled down later when traffic subsides. This is service/pod auto scaling.
3. To accommodate the increase in the pods more nodes are added to the cluster, later when there are less pods some nodes are shutdown and released. This is cluster auto scaling.

Unlike the above case, a daemonset has a 1 to 1 mapping to the nodes. And the N nodes = N pods kind of scaling will be useful only when 1 pods fits exactly to 1 node resources. This however, is very unlikely in real world scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Having a `Daemonset` has the downside that you might need to scale the application and therefore need to scale the number of nodes to add more pods. Also if you only need a few pods of the application but have a large cluster you might end up running a lot of unused pods that block resources for other applications.

Having a `Deployment` solves this problem, because two or more pods of the same application can run on one node and the number of pods is decoupled from the number of nodes per default. But this brings another problem: If your cluster is rather small and you have a small number of pods, they might end up all running on a few nodes. There is no good distribution over all available nodes. If some of those nodes fail for some reason you loose the majority of your application pods.

You can solve this using `PodAntiAffinity`, so pods can not run on a node where a defined other pod is running. By that you can have a similar behavior as a `Daemonset` but with far less pods and more flexibility regarding scaling and resource usage.

So a use case would be, when you don't need one pod per node but still want them to be distrubuted over your nodes. Say you have 50 nodes and an application of which you need 15 pods. Using a `Deployment` with `PodAntiAffinity` you can run those 15 pods in a distributed way on different 15 nodes. When you suddently need 20 you can scale up the application (not the nodes) so 20 pods run on 20 different nodes. But you never have 50 pods per default, where you only need 15 (or 20).

You could achieve the same with a `Daemonset` using `nodeSelector` or `taints`/`tolerations` but that would be far more complicated and less flexible.